# Survival-like curves in R

Tags: r, plot

I would like to create "survival" like curves using the following dataset:

```
mydata <- read.table(text="ID Onset_weeks Group
Sample1 15.57142857 A
Sample2 16 A
Sample3 14 A
Sample4 NA A
Sample5 16.14285714 A
Sample6 14.28571429 A
Sample7 NA A
Sample8 NA A
Sample9 NA A
Sample10 10.57142857 A
Sample11 14.28571429 B
Sample12 10.28571429 B
Sample13 18.28571429 B
Sample14 12.14285714 B
Sample15 12.14285714 B
Sample16 NA B
Sample17 15.85714286 B
Sample19 19.85714286 B", head=TRUE)
```

I would like to plot the % of individuals with the disease at each week (from 0 to 20 weeks). I would like to have two "survival" curves, one for each group (A, B), in the same plot.

I have tried the following code, but the two curves I get are going down rather than up as the script thinks "Onset_weeks" refer to death.

```
library(survival)
mydata$SurvObj <- with(mydata, Surv(Onset_weeks))
km.by.group <- survfit(SurvObj ~ Group, data = mydata, conf.type = "log-log")
plot(km.by.group)
```

Comment: Anything you already tried? SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @Heroka. I added my code above.

Comment: No.Two issues:  Survival curves _always_ are decreasing. And adding a Surv-object to a dataframe is just completely misguided. I have no idea what you intend to illustrate. Your question needs major reworking.

Comment: There are cumulative-hazard curves, but I agree with@42- that the question needs reworking. For instance, if Onset_weeks is missing, does that mean there are no data? Or was patient followed for x weeks and did not get the disease?

Comment: @Heroka, Yes, it means that patient was followed for x weeks and didn't get the disease.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `censor` flag needs to be constructed and the times for the censored cases needs to be set to the full duration of observation. Appears we are asked to think of this as a disease whose duration is chronic or at least extends past the end of the period of monitoring.

```
mydata$Onset_weeks[is.na(mydata$Onset_weeks)] <- 20
mydata$censor <- mydata$Onset_weeks != 20

km.by.group <- survfit(Surv(Onset_weeks, censor) ~ Group, data = mydata)
plot(km.by.group, fun='event')
```

Choosing the version of the plotting of a survfit object for what Therneau call the "competing events" display.

[image]